# EF with SQL server application role

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I need to use application rule security on sql server. And i want to use Enity Framework Code First.

After a successful login my connection is set to application role. I then create my DbContext using this connection.

But: EF expects a closed connection object. And closing a connection drops the application role.

How can i solve this dilemma?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to get this work with two steps:

Switch connection pooling off, which is mentioned all the time for connections using application roles. As i have a desktop application, this is no problem for me.

Add a handler to `DbConnection.StateChanged` and activate the application role on every opening of the connection. Without connection pooling, it is not necessary to `sp_unsetapprole` on closing. So this works for me:

```
context.Database.Connection.StateChanged += (sender, args) =>
  if (args.CurrentState == ConnectionState.Open) {
    activateAppRole((DbConnection)sender, ...);
  }
}
```

I guess, if Pooling is vital for someone, she may call `sp_unsetapprole` on closing the connection in this same handler.

Answer (score 4):

Since this question is high on the search result list, I just wanted to throw in a word of caution. I have an app that needed to use an application role and ***okrumnow***'s solution seemed at first to work.

However, in unit testing I discovered that sometimes handling the StateChanged event will cause the event to be raised twice and you'll get the error:

> "Impersonate Session Security Context" cannot be called in this batch because a simultaneous batch has called it.

It seems to help to change the conditional to:

```cs
args.CurrentState == ConnectionState.Open &&
    args.CurrentState == ConnectionState.Closed
```

But it still doesn't eliminate the error. I confirmed this in EF4.3 and EF5. ***Ladislav*** is correct that the ideal way is creating a connection for the DbContext and telling the context that it doesn't own it.

Also, connection pooling is never possible with this setup since there is no `ConnectionState.Closing` event where you can call `sp_unsetapprole` before your connection is closed.

Since I had the flexibility, my solution was to eliminate the usage of an app role and using a dedicated SQL login instead. Either way you're hard-coding a password...

Answer (score 0):

EF doesn't have any native support for this. I guess the workaround can be:

- Creating your own connection and passing it (closed) to EF context / EntityConnection. This should enforce that you will have connection lifetime under your control and EF will not close it (but I already saw complains that it doesn't work with DbContext).
- Once you have instance of the context created set application role. Context itself should not generate any queries to the database (except DbContext with code first checking version of the database) so setting the role after context creation should not cause any problems.

Comment: Unfortunately, DbContext is opening and closing the connection all the time, so your guesses don't work.